# PHP get selected text from select box and get the email

Tags: php, html, email

for now i was receiving in my email account only the values but i want the text from the selection how to do that here is my code :

```
<select name="selectoption">
    <option value='0'>Choose Server..</option>
    <option value='1'>L2 EmpireAge 70x</option>
    <option value='2'>L2 EmpireAge Warfire 150x</option>
    <option value='3'>L2 EmpireAge Classic 30x</option>
    </select>


$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$select_server = $_POST['selectoption'];
$select_weapon = $_POST['weaponid'];


$to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. /n ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Password: $password \n Server_Id: $select_server \n  Weapon_Id: $select_weapon  ";
```

Comment: *Oh, by the way...* `/n` you need to invert that slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like an array to store the values, see this example:

```
<?php

$array[0] = 'Choose Server..';
$array[1] = 'L2 EmpireAge 70x';
$array[2] = 'L2 EmpireAge Warfire 150x';
$array[3] = 'L2 EmpireAge Classic 30x';
?>

<select name="selectoption">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo "<option value='{$i}'>{$array[$i]}</option>";
}   
?>
</select>


$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$select_server = $_POST['selectoption'];
$select_weapon = $_POST['weaponid'];

//Your server info is here
$info = $array[$select_server];
```

Comment: I am sorry guys it was my first post i will be more careful with my next !!! Thanks For Your Answer